# Is there an equivalent PyTorch function for `tf.nn.space_to_depth`

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

As the title says, is there an equivalent PyTorch function for [tf.nn.space_to_depth](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/space_to_depth)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While [torch.nn.functional.pixel_shuffle](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html#torch.nn.functional.pixel_shuffle) does exactly what `tf.nn.depth_to_space` does, PyTorch doesn't have any function to do the inverse operation similar to `tf.nn.space_to_depth`.

That being said, it is easy to implement `space_to_depth` using [torch.nn.functional.unfold](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/functional.html#unfold).

```py
def space_to_depth(x, block_size):
    n, c, h, w = x.size()
    unfolded_x = torch.nn.functional.unfold(x, block_size, stride=block_size)
    return unfolded_x.view(n, c * block_size ** 2, h // block_size, w // block_size)
```

Comment: FYI: pytorch now provides [pixel-unshuffle](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html#pixel-unshuffle) which is similar to `tf.space_to_depth`

Comment: @Jon The two functions do not seem to be equivalent. Putting a random vector into both functions (making sure to use `NCHW` data format for TF), the outputs are not identical.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, @Priyatham's unfold is not correct.
`Unfold` will enlarge/expand channel by `block_size * block_size`, but the `space-to-depth` requires duplicate channel by `block_size * block_size` (means copy channel by `block_size * block_size`)

So, the right way is to use `eniops.rearrange()`:

```
result = einops.rearrange(x, 'b c (h p1) (w p2) -> b (p1 p2) h w', p1=block_size, p2=block_size)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow Tresnet Github  official sourceode
`https://github.com/Alibaba-MIIL/TResNet/blob/master/src/models/tresnet/layers/space_to_depth.py`

Answer (score 0):

I am late to the party, but I have faced the same problem in a handful of projects, so I ended up by publishing the implementation as a PyPi package:

https://github.com/lnstadrum/s2d2s

In a nutshell,

- `PixelShuffle`/`PixelUnshuffle` is not numerically equivalent to `depth_to_space`/`space_to_depth`, unless the upsampled image has a single channel. While the tensor dimensions match between the PyTorch and TensorFlow counterparts, the output channels do not follow the same order. I therefore agree with @HeCao: **the accepted answer is not correct**.
- `depth_to_space`/`space_to_depth` are supported by some inference frameworks (e.g., Android NN API, at the moment of writing), so there might be performance benefits to use them when building a model from scratch. The provided implementation automatically maps the corresponding PyTorch layers to `SpaceToDepth`/`DepthToSpace` ONNX ops when exporting a PyTorch model as an ONNX graph for further deployment.